User keeps asking for Android Trojans RATs on at least 3 sites - Should be kicked off
This user  Gregor keeps asking for somewhere to download Trojans.  He has been at it for 20 days or more.  He has asked here 3 times and has also asked on Software Recommendations, Information Security and Super User.  I think that he should be shut down before he finds a Trojan to wreak havoc on us all.

In short, I disagree about "kicking" a user based on this. I agree the questions are not suitable, but I don't think that I am seeing the same reason. Please note that on the meta sites downvotes indicate disagreement in discussions (or proposals) and are not about your question being bad.

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. Generally (from a community member perspective) I don't find these questions suitable for this Q&A site.
However, given links were already shared and sites offering what the user searches abound (minus the search/filter options), I don't exactly see what's wrong with asking for malware?
It's a stated (as was communicated to us mods) policy by SE to not have worry about the legality or have them enforce laws (besides, which jurisdiction should be considered?). The issue is similar to questions about cracking, I think. And so is the conclusion: downvote unsuitable or low quality questions independently of the legality aspect.
